# Discord.js any way to get all roles

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How would you get all the roles in a server using Discord.js? I've `message.guild.roles` but from there it's a mystery to me.

Comment: The first thing I would do is check the docs, which state that `Guild.roles` is a collection of `Role`s. As far as I'm concerned, its a regular array. So, to get all the roles you will want to iterate over it. `for ( let i = 0; i < roles.length; i++ ) { let role = roles[ i ]; ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by the other answer and your question [`message.guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=guild) indeed has a property [`roles`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=roles):

> `.roles`
> A collection of roles that are in this guild. The key is the role's ID, the value is the role
> Type: `Collection <Snowflake, Role>`

A collection extends the JavaScript type [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and add some function for you to use.

You indeed have all the roles of the guild (server) with `message.guild.roles`.
Now if you want to do anything with it, for example list them, check the function in [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection) / the type map.

```js
message.guild.roles.forEach(role => console.log(role.name, role.id))
```

will print each role name + id in the console.

Answer (score 3):

```js
 let rolemap = message.guild.roles.cache
            .sort((a, b) => b.position - a.position)
            .map(r => r)
            .join(",");
            if (rolemap.length > 1024) rolemap = "To many roles to display";
            if (!rolemap) rolemap = "No roles";
    const embed = Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .addField("Role List" , rolemap)
    message.channel.send(embed);
```

Here's how to get all roles in a guild in discord.js v12