# how to get a list of all id roles from a discord server

Tags: discord.js

I actually want to create 2 lists: one containing the role id and the other one containing the role names. I have tried to read the API (https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#get-guild-roles) and the topic that was created last year ([Discord.js any way to get all roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58780548/discord-js-any-way-to-get-all-roles)) but neither of them worked for me. I'm new to js and i don't know if i should learn more about js before continuing.

Comment: `message.guild.roles.cache.map(r => /* r.name or r.id */)`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get two lists of guild roles and guild names:

```js
cosnt roleIds = message.guild.roles.cache.map(role => role.id);
const roleNames = message.guild.roles.cache.map(role => role.name);
```

`message.guild.roles.cache` is a Discord.js [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/stable/class/Collection) (Collections are a custom Discord.js data structure, which they use to store pretty much everything.)

I would recommend that you read the Discord.js docs for [`Collection#map()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=map) in order to better understand the solution that I have provided. This method is identical in behaviour to [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).